# Msg 3623, An invalid floating point operation occurred

Tags: sql, t-sql

When I tried to update some tables value I got this error.

I have table with column some float values

```
 Values 
 ---------------------
 11.7830808596997
 -9.41220524769667
  1.70771403155729
-26.1598813945345
  1.40722323420305
  0.315202798180501
 -3.27870943910565
  4.49832736699458
-21.8406197004573
 12.6569938818624
 10.3327211608816
-14.9366297400332
 -1.96665717283736
  5.90430556370099
  1.59122918690946
  1.01784176743728
-41.3800628432377
```

Now I want to change to power of 0.3333 with all that value.

So I write a statement

```
update table 
set value = power(value, 0.3333)
```

But I get an error

> Msg 3623
> An invalid floating point operation occurred

Can you suggest how I can fix that? I want to do something like

```
(1 + value) ^ 1/3 - 1
```

in T-SQL

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the logic you want:

```
select sign(val) * exp(log(abs(val)) / 3)
from (select -8 as val) t
```

The issue is that you cannot raise negative numbers to fractional powers because the result is generally an imaginary number, not a floating point number.  This simple converts the value to a positive number and remembers the sign.

You *could* also use:

```
select sign(val) * power(abs(val), 1.0 / 3)
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e02b1817adc3757da1cffc99e97a0090) is a db<>fiddle.